# systemctl start service does not work in SPEC file

Tags: rhel, rpm-spec, systemctl

I met a problem that the command "sudo systemctl start xxx.service" in my SPEC file does not work when upgrading my RPM package, following is my %post script in SPEC file,

```
%post
echo "---------------------------- post $1 -------------------------------"
# refresh installation
if [ $1 == 1 ]; then
  sudo echo "Installation finished."
# upgrade installation
elif [ $1 -gt 1 ]; then
  sudo echo "Starting service xxx.service..."
  sudo /usr/bin/systemctl enable xxx.service > /dev/null 2>&1
  sudo /usr/bin/systemctl start xxx.service
  sleep 10
  sudo echo "Finished."
fi
exit 0
```

I'm sure that the service file already exists in directory /usr/lib/systemd/system, and I can start it manually using the command "sudo systemctl start xxx.service".

And I found that the "sleep 10" command does not work too.

Very appreciated if there is any suggestion about this issue, thanks.

Comment: `systemctl daemon-reload` is needed before new service files are seen.

Comment: Also, `==` is not guaranteed to be supported in `[`/`test`. The only string comparison operator the POSIX standard specifies is just a single `=`, so whether `==` works depends on the active shell.

Comment: Also, do not use `sudo` here. Package installations already run as root.

Comment: Beyond that, I would strongly suggest using `set -x` to enable trace logging -- and *not* redirecting stderr, at least until after you have things working.

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy, thanks for your suggestions, I printed out the log, everything seems ok, no error occurs, and the command "systemctl start xxx.service" return 0, but the service still does not start, also, there is no log indicate that someone triggered the service startup event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few issues:

- You're not supposed to use `sudo` in scriplets, because 1) it may not be installed 2) rpm installation runs as superuser anyway
- You should use the standard [RPM macros for SystemD](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#_scriptlets) as opposed to reinventing the wheel.

Essentially that simply goes down to:

```
%{?systemd_requires}
BuildRequires: systemd

# ...

%post
%systemd_post %{name}.service

%preun
%systemd_preun %{name}.service

%postun
%systemd_postun_with_restart %{name}.service

# ...
```

Take note that the SystemD macros for CentOS/RHEL are within `systemd` package, while in Fedora they are now in `systemd-rpm-macros`.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the service startup command in the scriptlet "%posttrans" resolves my problem, thanks for all your suggestions.